# Plotting points on a circle, where each point is further from the origin based on how often it is present. Weird behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, normal-distribution

I have a large amount of hue values expressed in degrees (0 to 360) that I wish to plot on a circle.

Here is some 'test' data. My real data is similar to this.

```
# create values with a normal distributions. 
mu = 0.5
sigma = 0.02
values = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,10000)
values = values*360
```

Now I create a simple circle.

```
# create a circle
circle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
x = np.sin(circle)
y = np.cos(circle)
plt.plot(x,y,color='black')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Next, I wish to plot my data onto this circle.

```
# plot values on circle
x = []
y = []
for i in values:
    x.append(round(math.cos(math.radians(i)),2))
    y.append(round(math.sin(math.radians(i)),2))
plt.scatter(x,y,color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Hmmm. Okay, so the values are plotted onto the circle. But now it looks as if the points are more-or-less equally likely within the spread. I would like to show the data in such a way, that you can see the distribution of the data too. Something like a normal bell curve. That is, I would like something like this (don't mind the bad paint skills)

[image]

In this image, the further away from the black circle, the more often we find these data points. Basically, a circular normal bell curve.

I tried to multiply each data-point by a value that increases as the likelihood for that value increases. I.e, the more likely the data-point, the further away it is from the black circle. (Just as a bell curve, but than on a circle) but it is giving me these weird results.

```
uniqueX = set(x)
uniqueY = set(y)
countx = max([x.count(i) for i in set(x)])
county = min([y.count(i) for i in set(y)])

ofset = [((1/countx*x.count(i))+1) for i in x]
x = [x*ofset[ii] for ii,x in enumerate(x)]
y = [x*ofset[ii] for ii,x in enumerate(y)]

plt.scatter(x,y,color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This output is not what I had inentend. I'm not sure where I am going wrong (my geometry and math has never been my strong suit). How can I make my desired plot?

My data looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you would rather like to show a kernel density estimate of your distribution?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

mu = 0.5
sigma = 0.1
values = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,10000)
values = values

phi = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
xc = np.sin(phi)
yc = np.cos(phi)
plt.plot(xc,yc,color='black')


kde = gaussian_kde(values)
r = kde(phi)

# scale the kde by 1/10 to make it fit to the screen
x = (1+r/10.)*np.cos(phi)
y = (1+r/10.)*np.sin(phi)
plt.plot(x,y,color='red', zorder=0)


plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Possibly you also want to show this on a polar plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

mu = 0.5
sigma = 0.1
values = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,10000)
values = values

phi = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
r0 = np.ones_like(phi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"))
ax.plot(phi,r0,color='black')


kde = gaussian_kde(values)
r = kde(phi)

# scale the kde by 1/10 to make it fit to the screen
ax.plot(phi,(1+r/10),color='red', zorder=0)

ax.set_rgrids([])
ax.set_rlim(ymax=1.2*(1+r/10).max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The code appears to work with the test data, but when I plot my own data, it just  shows a flat line across the circle. I've added a plot of my data's distribution to the question

Comment: Mind that you need to decide if you want to work in radiants or degrees. Using radiants throughout simlifies things.